# SourceTree tree view was there but now it has vanished

Tags: sourcetree

Having recently updated to `SourceTree v1.8.2.11`, I no longer have tree view. Such a handy feature. Where is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most recent releases of SourceTree have caused people a lot of heartache.  One of the things they removed was the tree view for staging files.  Most people are rolling back to 1.7.x.  To do the same, see [this thread](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/36183540/how-to-downgrade-sourcetree-to-2.0-or-2.1).

Answer (score 1):

You had one job Source *Tree*

Also dragging to Staged files window stopped working. Don't fix what's not broken Atlassian...

Latest old UI version(just checked and tree view works in this version)
https://www.reddit.com/r/sourcetree/comments/47bgfn/download_link_for_version_17032509_old_ui_for/?